# Graphics not appearing in a Webview

Tags: cocoa, webview, core-plot

This question follows on from a previous question:
[Problems creating a Webview for printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838520/problems-creating-a-webview-for-printing)

I am using a Webview to print plots created using the Core Plot framework. The following code is being used to populate the Webview:

```
    NSData        *imageData = [[barChart imageOfLayer] TIFFRepresentation];
NSString      *temporaryImagePath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSError       *error = nil;

NSBitmapImageRep*   imageRep    = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
NSData*             pngData;

pngData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType 
                                 properties:nil];

temporaryImagePath = [temporaryImagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"jpegData.jpg" ];
[pngData writeToFile:temporaryImagePath 
               options:NSDataWritingAtomic 
                 error:&error ];

WebView *printView;

printView =[[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 1000)
                                frameName:@"printFrame" 
                                groupName:@"printGroup"];

NSString *theCSSString = [self theFileCodeForString:@"OutputFormat"
                                      withExtension:@"CSS"
                                       withContents:@"<style type=\"text/css\">#results {font-family:\"Trebuchet MS\", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;} #results td, #results th {font-size:1em;border:1px solid #98bf21;padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;} #results th {font-size:1.1em;text-align:left;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#A7C942;color:#ffffff;} #results tr.alt td {color:#000000;background-color:#EAF2D3;} </style>"];

NSMutableString *theURLString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html>"];
[theURLString appendString:@"<head>"];
[theURLString appendString:theCSSString];
[theURLString appendString:@"</head>"];

[theURLString appendString:@"<body>"];
NSURL *tempImageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:temporaryImagePath];
[theURLString appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\"/>", [tempImageURL absoluteString]];
[theURLString appendString:@"</body></html>"];

[[printView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:theURLString
                  baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"xxxx"]];

[[[[printView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] print:sender];
[printView release];
```

My problem is that the image is not appearing in either the printed version of the Webview or if I instantiate a window with the Webview in it the image does not appear. If I take the raw HTML generated by the code though, paste it into Coda and then preview it the image appears with no problems. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to fix this. It is probably a fairly basic error as I'm fairly new to working with images and Webviews.

**Edit**

It looks like the problem relates to the format of the link to the image because when I replace the generated file:///... link with a html://... link with an image on the web everything seems to work fine. This doesn't explain why it works in Coda but not in the Webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Setting the baseURL to tempImageURL solved the problem. Everything is good.